# How to implement my own action in custom admin grid?

Tags: magento2, php

I have custom admin grid which shows data from my table.
Last column in this table is "Actions".
And there are two actions (links) - "Approve" and "Reject".
My links looks like:

http://mgtraining.box/admin_18vp0y/grid/grid/approve/id/1/key/

http://mgtraining.box/admin_18vp0y/grid/grid/reject/id/1/key/

How to make custom actions for each link with redirect back to grid?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fight, fight and win.

1) Create file [Vendor]/[Module]/Controller/Adminhtml/Approve/Index.php

2) Fill this file with code below:

```
<?php

    namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Controller\Adminhtml\Approve;

    class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
    {

        public function execute()
        {
            // In this variable you will have id from your URL
            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

            // Here will be your code

            $this->_redirect('grid/grid/index');
        }

        protected function _isAllowed() {
            // grid_list - your layout file
            return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('[Vendor]_[Module]::grid_list');
        }
    }
```

3) Type in console: `magento setup:upgrade`